# How do i enter text and formula into a cell via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am puzzled,,,

Here are two lines,  the lower one works EXCAKTLY as i exspect it to.
The top one, does not, either i get syntax error, or formula error missing = or : it says.

I know the lower one at this moment has  5x  "
and the topone is 4x "  however when i add the 5th i get the syntax error.

```
If i <= taskNo Then VS.Range(ColumnLetter(i + 18) & 7).Formula = "=Calculations!" & ColumnLetter(i + 2) & 53 & ""& test""

    If i > taskNo Then VS.Range(ColumnLetter(i + 18) & 7).Formula = "=Calculations!A1 & "" test"""
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To make your first formula produce a similar result to the first, use

```
"=Calculations!" & ColumnLetter(i + 2) & 53 & " & "" test"""
```

for `i = 1` it will produce

```
=Calculations!A53 & " test"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm,,   i guess it was  the " & " that was messing me up ;)